How to put downarrow and comments closer to the equations?. \ArrowBetweenLines*[\downarrow] from mathtools package
How to put closer the downarrow and comments?

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}  
  2.75x+77.4-1.80x &=104.95&&\\
  \ArrowBetweenLines*[\downarrow\mathrlap{\text{Comment 02.}}]
  0.95x&=27.55 &&\\  
  \Aboxed{x&=29} &&    %%% <- This is the box I would like with rounded corners.
\end{align*}

\end{document} 


Use alignat instead of align.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  2.75x+77.4-1.80x &=104.95\\
  &&\downarrow\text{Comment 02.}\\
  0.95x&=27.55\\  
  \Aboxed{x&=29}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document} 


You may use \ArrowBetweenLines, if you so prefer.
